# Sum row values based on previous ones

Tags: r

I'll try to be specific: I want to create a new column on a data frame in which the values are the sum of the previous values in another column.

So I already have the first two columns (ID and Value) below and want to create the third one (Sum), but I don't know how to do this.

In the column "Sum", the values are the sum of the values in "Value), so for example, 31.098 (Sum) is the sum of 16.91 and 14.18 (Value):

```
ID     Value       Sum
157 16.91531834 16.91531834
142 14.18365203 31.09897037
205 11.93528052 43.03425089
89  11.83021643 54.86446732
53  6.3668838   61.23135112
204 3.99243539  65.22378651
202 3.21496113  68.43874764
17  1.93317924  70.37192688
220 1.74406388  72.11599076
147 1.59697415  73.71296491
33  1.42887161  75.14183652
138 1.28178189  76.42361841
154 1.19773062  77.62134903
```

It is the first time I'm posting here. Until now I found everything I was searching for already answered... so, sorry if this kind of question is already answered too (I must have been!), but I wasn't able to find. I'm not a native speaker (as you probably guessed already), so maybe I didn't use the proper key words...

Thanks!!

Comment: You need `cumsum` i.e. `df1$Sum <- cumsum(df1$Value)`

Comment: Also you can use the `dplyr package`; `data %>% mutate( newVar = cumsum(oldVar)`

Comment: Thanks, akrun and Cristóbal!

Also, if I want to select, say, the first 80% of the values in this table, how could I do this?

Comment: @Sotos Another approach?

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar Using `mutate` to create the new variable and `%>%` for pipping it does not show another approach (also using `cumsum`). It only shows unnecessary calling of a package.

Comment: Ok, you have a point. Maybe is only verbose in the particular operation of `cumsum`, but could be more friendly from the view of interact with the data, and extensible to more operations in a more intuitive and readable way.

Comment: you are overthinking it. No need for packages for such simple operations